# Can we build Kotin and Java Mix application?

Tags: android, kotlin

**I started learning kotlin , but as I had good work experience in making android application in java language.So i want to use my native java experience with Kotlin.So I had some queries:**

- If we used some of the files in Kotlin language and some in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer yes you can.

> If we used some of the files in Kotlin language and some in java?

You can use both java and Kotlin in a single class file.

> Does it affect at the time of uploading in playstore?

No

> Best way or tutorial to learn kotlin?

- https://kotlinlang.org/
- Kotlin for android developers ebook

> I had also tried flutter but as I don't have much knowledge of dart language.So I switch towards kotlin. Let me know I am right or wrong?

Yes, you are. However you can also play with Flutter besides Kotlin. Its pretty cool.

Comment: `You can use both java and Kotlin in a single class file.`---this is kind of a confusing sentence. Yes, you can access classes written in java and kotlin from the same class, but you can't write kotlin and java in a single source code file.